# Webapp fails with net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with Ubuntu 18.04.4 Server Edition but works fine with Ubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop

Tags: 18.04, server, webapp-development, websocket

I put in this repository a tiny testing webapp: https://github.com/marcoippolito/testproject

If I git clone it in a laptop using Linux 5.3 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

with this environment:

```
(base) marco@marco-U36SG:~/vueMatters/testproject$ vue info

Environment Info:

  System:
    OS: Linux 5.3 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.14.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.13.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 79.0.3945.130
    Firefox: 72.0.2
  npmPackages:
    @vue/babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props:  1.0.0 
    @vue/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-preset-app:  4.1.2 
    @vue/babel-preset-jsx:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-functional-vue:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-inject-h:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-v-model:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-v-on:  1.1.2 
    @vue/cli-overlay:  4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-plugin-babel: ^4.1.2 => 4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-plugin-eslint: ^4.1.2 => 4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-plugin-router:  4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-plugin-vuex:  4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-service: ^4.1.0 => 4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-shared-utils:  4.1.2 
    @vue/component-compiler-utils:  3.1.1 
    @vue/preload-webpack-plugin:  1.1.1 
    @vue/web-component-wrapper:  1.2.0 
    eslint-plugin-vue: ^5.0.0 => 5.2.3 
    vue: ^2.6.10 => 2.6.11 
    vue-eslint-parser:  5.0.0 
    vue-hot-reload-api:  2.3.4 
    vue-loader:  15.8.3 
    vue-style-loader:  4.1.2 
    vue-template-compiler: ^2.6.10 => 2.6.11 
    vue-template-es2015-compiler:  1.9.1 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    @vue/cli: 4.1.2
```

and then run the webapp:

```
(base) marco@marco-U36SG:~/vueMatters/testproject$ npm run serve

> testproject@0.1.0 serve /home/marco/vueMatters/testproject
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 6588ms                                                               3:37:24 PM


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080 
  - Network: http://192.168.1.4:8080

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

I get the webpage with no error message in the web developer's console:
[image]

But if I git clone the same repository into Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS Server Edition:

```
(base) marco@pc:~/vueMatters/testproject$ vue info

Environment Info:

  System:
    OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.11.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.11.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.11.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.11.0/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: Not Found
    Firefox: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @vue/babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props:  1.0.0 
    @vue/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-preset-app:  4.1.2 
    @vue/babel-preset-jsx:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-functional-vue:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-inject-h:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-v-model:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-v-on:  1.1.2 
    @vue/cli-overlay:  4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-plugin-babel: ^4.1.0 => 4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-plugin-eslint: ^4.1.0 => 4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-plugin-router:  4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-plugin-vuex:  4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-service: ^4.1.0 => 4.1.2 
    @vue/cli-shared-utils:  4.1.2 
    @vue/component-compiler-utils:  3.1.1 
    @vue/preload-webpack-plugin:  1.1.1 
    @vue/web-component-wrapper:  1.2.0 
    eslint-plugin-vue: ^5.0.0 => 5.2.3 
    vue: ^2.6.11 => 2.6.11 
    vue-eslint-parser:  5.0.0 
    vue-hot-reload-api:  2.3.4 
    vue-loader:  15.8.3 
    vue-style-loader:  4.1.2 
    vue-template-compiler: ^2.6.10 => 2.6.11 
    vue-template-es2015-compiler:  1.9.1 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    @vue/cli: 4.1.2
```

And, after stopping the nginx server:

```
(base) marco@pc:~/vueMatters/testproject$ sudo systemctl stop nginx
[sudo] password for marco: 
(base) marco@pc:~/vueMatters/testproject$ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy 
server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2020-02-03 16:14:07 CET; 5s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 5749 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry
QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 919 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process 
on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 891 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; 
master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 925 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 03 14:46:29 pc systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server 
and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 03 14:46:30 pc systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server 
and a reverse proxy server.
Feb 03 16:14:07 pc systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server 
and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 03 16:14:07 pc systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server 
and a reverse proxy server.
```

I run the tiny web-app:

```
(base) marco@pc:~/vueMatters/testproject$ npm run serve

> testproject@0.1.0 serve /home/marco/vueMatters/testproject
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 1376ms                                                                                                                                                               4:16:25 PM


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080 
  - Network: http://192.168.1.7:8080

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

I get this errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1580743078903 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

[image]

Comparing the two environment infos, the only difference is the OS installed:
- In the laptop, where the tiny webapp is regularly working fine,
      Linux 5.3 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver) Desktop
- In the pc, where the tiny webapp is giving the error 
  "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED",
      Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver) Server Edition

I didn't install any 18.04.4 version. On July 2019 I installed 18.04.02 Ubuntu Server Edition and till few days ago regularly upgraded the packages, as requested and suggested by the system. So, the label "18.04.4" comes from the upgrading process, which didn't at all, I'm 100% sure, declared the upgraded packages as "development version", otherwise I would have not proceed in the upgrading.

So... how to solve the problem?

Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Big Update with Partial "Solution":

In the PC I installed ex-novo Ubuntu 18.04.3 Desktop and I verified that the problem disappeared.

I ran the same tiny webapp in both laptop and pc, and using localhost and the ip-address both from within the laptop/PC and from the other device (PC/laptop) gave no error:

WebApp running on the PC:

Localhost from PC:
[image]

PC-IP address from PC:
[image]

PC-IP address from Laptop:
[image]

WebApp running on the laptop:

Localhost from the laptop:

[image]

Laptop-IP address from the laptop:

[image]

Laptop-IP address from the PC:

[image]

So...at this point the final questions are:
Why with Ubuntu 18.04.4 Server Edition we have ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and with Ubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop this problem disappears?
How to solve the problem in Ubuntu 18.04.3 Server Edition?

Comment: @K7AAY I didn't install any 18.04.4 version. On July 2019 I installed 18.04.02 Ubuntu Server Edition and till few days ago regularly upgraded the packages, as requested and suggested by the system. So, the label "18.04.4" comes from the upgrading process, which didn't at all, I'm 100% sure, declared the upgraded packages as "development version", otherwise I would have not proceed in the upgrading

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing the server version has a firewall installed that is preventing connections.